# Does transition to GBAS navigation require alignment of the intermediate segment with final segment?

Tags: iaps, gbas

I am studying how the Ground Based Augmentation System (GBAS) affects the Instrument Approach Procedures, and I noticed that in ICAO's Aircraft Operations manual (8168, Volume II) it states:

> Part III, Section 3, Chapter 6, 6.3.2: "The intermediate approach segment of a GBAS procedure shall be aligned with the final approach course."

I would like to make sure if the rule concerning the alignment of the intermediate segment with the final segment implies that the whole segment (each leg of the intermediate segment) has to be aligned with the final, rather than only the last leg.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think this is close enough to your SBAS question that they could be combined.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience, since the question concerns different navigation system (GBAS instead of SBAS), I thought that it was appropriate to open a separate thread. But you are right, probably I should combine them. I will edit the other question to include the GBAS navigation system.